# Sitecore form Redirect to page submit a action redirecting to wrong url

Tags: sitecore-forms, redirect

I am using Sitecore 10.1. The Sitecore form's `redirect to page submit action` is redirecting to the wrong url.

I have two Sites in the `Sitegrouping (Auth and Prod)`. Auth Site is using the master database while Prod site is using the web database.

```
The Auth url is https://pointmarina-sc10-staging-cm.com
The Prod url is https://pointmarina-sc10-staging-cd.com
```

[image: sitegrouoing]

When I am submitting the form using the prod url then it is redirecting to the auth url.

For-example, When submitting the form using the prod url `(https://pointmarina-sc10-staging-cm.com/e-news)` then, it should redirect to `https://pointmarina-sc10-staging-cd.com/thank-you` but it is redirecting to the auth url `https://pointmarina-sc10-staging-cm.com/thank-you`

It is not happening with all the sites. Some sites are redirecting correctly but some sites are redirecting to the auth url.

Has anyone experienced this issue? Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hope that Thank you page is available in Web DB

Comment: yeah it is @Thamizh